# Android phone without GPU

Tags: gpu

I am developing an app and I am considering phones that have low GPU config. I want to know is/was there a phone without GPU?

Answer (score 0):

HTC Tattoo and Samsung Spica don't have GPU at all.

<sub>*Edited in from comments:*</sub>

These devices had chipsets which used software rendering (Snapdragon S1 (MSM7225) for the HTC and a proprietary chipset (Samsung S3C6410) for the Samsung), so there was no dedicated GPU, and the CPU took on the work of the GPU too.

Comment: That's kind of a play on words though... the Snapdragon S1 used in the HTC Tattoo (MSM7225) and the proprietary chipset used in the Samsung Spica both used software rendering... they had a GPU, but not a dedicated one, the CPU shared the load for GPU work.